Azure Alert Rule: Hopping Window(run every n hours, query data of last n+m hours)
I have an Azure Function that every 4 hours runs a database query and writes logs to app insights in case of errors found.
I create an Azure Alert rule with this query:
union traces, exceptions
| where message startswith "Reconciliation error" or message startswith "Reconciliation check failed"

Intention is: trigger every 4h, query last 5 hours, and if anything is there, raise alert.
Setting Alert rule granularity: 5h and Frequency of evaluation: 4h means there will be a sliding window, but I just want to run this every 4 hours.
Is it possible to achieve hopping window functionality instead?
Note: This docs page metnions a Lookback period "Select how far back to look each time the data is checked. For example, every 1 minute, look back 5 minutes."
but I dont see any such option in the portal

When using custom log search, the Lookback period option will not be displayed in the Portal; you must specify it within your query. As per MS Doc  Lookback period will support only metrics alert not for log search alert

You can refer this  MS Docs  to check  Lookback period option in alert. the option will available if you select any metrics, here is the option, You can use Logic Apps to fulfil your requirement.


Note: This docs  metnions a Lookback period "Select how far back to look each time the data is checked. For example, every 1 minute, look back 5 minutes." but I dont see any such option in the portal

The Lookback period option will only be available for metric alerts not for log search alerts.  Follow the  MS Docs to check Lookback period option in Alert.
When using custom log search, the Lookback period option will not be displayed in the Portal, instead you can set the Override query time range under Advanced.
If you need more fine grained control of the queried time period you can use a query,like:
query | where timestamp > ago(5h)

Note that this will automatically set to Override query time range its maximum of 2 days, as that is what ultimately dictates how much you can actually query.

So how would one go about making raising an alert based on a hopping window of logs?

You can use timestamp in query | where timestamp > ago(5h) , Azure Monitor will check logs from the past 5 hours during each evaluation and alert evaluation frequency of every 4 hours, Alerts will trigger if matching logs are found within that 5-hour window, but any issues will be detected and alerted up to 4 hours after they occur due to the evaluation interval.

I thought that the alert rule automatically filters for the last "Alert rule granularity" amount of hours?
Am I wrong or does that behaviour change when specifying the timestamp in the query itself?

Thanks for the help. I edited the question to answer the log search case I was asking about. After testing around the alert rule behaviour I found that the actual setting to look into is the "Override query time range" under advanced, unfoprtunately undocumented as far as I could find in msdn
